# Noise artifacts when recording HDR videos

Tags: video-quality, video-recording, noise

I have a Google Pixel 7 smartphone with support for HDR (10 bit) video recording technology in 4k 30 frames. And I was wondering how the environment affects the shooting of this video format. When recording HDR in good daylight, the picture really becomes pleasant and colorful in appearance, but for example, when shooting a single light source in a room (with an average brightness level) at the edges of the video, in places where there is relatively little illumination (the light source in the center of the frame), strong noise begins to appear, which is observed in the form of lots of vertical stripes. At the same time, if I shoot a video with the HDR mode turned off in the same conditions, then this noise will not be noticeable (well, accordingly, the video will be with a smaller range of colors). I tried changing the exposure and noticed that when the exposure is lowered, there is less noise, but dark objects in the photo become less distinguishable as a result.

1. So, how does using this mode affect the final video and why, under the same conditions, may there be noise from turning on HDR?
2. When do you think it is worth and not worth using this mode?
3. What needs to be monitored when using it (settings or objects in the frame)?

I apologize in advance to the professionals, I do not understand this topic well, I would like to learn more in simple and understandable language) Thank you